# Puppet does not honor 'require' modules

Tags: ruby, puppet

I have created a module to add a user as follows:

```
user { 'test':
    ensure => 'present',
    comment => 'Test User',
    home => '/home/test',
    shell => '/bin/bash',
    managehome => 'true',
    gid => 'postgres',
    groups => 'users',
    password => '$1$PIp.c9J6$gdAyd76OhBk7n9asda80wm0',
    require => [ Package['rubygem-ruby-shadow'], Class['postgres'] ],
}
```

It requires the class postgres as I need its primary group to be assigned to postgres, and the rubygem-ruby-shadow dependency is for the password setup.

My problem is puppet does not honor these requirements. Puppet will always execute the useradd module first before rubygem-ruby-shadow, and this causes the password setup to fail. I have also tried to include rubygem-ruby-shadow in the same class as useradd but to no avail.

The output upon `running puppet agent -t`:

```
linux-z14x:~ # puppet agent -t
info: Caching catalog for linux-z14x.playground.local
info: /User[test]: Provider useradd does not support features manages_passwords; not managing attribute password
info: Applying configuration version '1425978163'
notice: /Stage[main]/Users/Package[rubygem-ruby-shadow]/ensure: created
notice: /User[test]/ensure: created
notice: Finished catalog run in 78.19 seconds
```

Running it the second time:

```
linux-z14x:~ # puppet agent -t
info: Caching catalog for linux-z14x.playground.local
info: Applying configuration version '1425978163'
notice: /Stage[main]/Users/User[test]/password: changed password
notice: Finished catalog run in 74.79 seconds
```

My rubygem-ruby-shadow class:

```
package { 'rubygem-ruby-shadow':
        ensure => 'installed',
        require => Class['myrepo'],
        provider => 'zypper',
}
```

How do I get rubygem-ruby-shadow module to run first before the useradd?

Puppet master version is 3.7.4-1 (on CentOS) and puppet client is 2.6.12-0.10.1 (on SLES 11 SP2).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunate. The provider detects the absence of `ruby-shadow` during agent initialization, and does not update its capabilities during the transaction.

This may be limitation of Puppet that might be fixed in a more recent version (what are you using?)

I do try and make sure to provide `ruby-shadow` along with Puppet itself everywhere, to avoid this very issue.

Comment: Puppet client version is 2.6.12-0.10.1. Too much hassle with dependencies when I tried to upgrade it to a later version, and considering that I'm using puppet only for a one time setup, I don't want to put so much time in finding the solution. I don't have the access to my puppet server now so I will try to place the `ruby-shadow` part in the top scope and rerun it tomorrow. Do you think it will make any difference?

Thanks @FelixFrank.

Comment: It will definitely **not** make a difference. What I'm saying is that you can either (a) settle for two Puppet runs or (b) do `zypper install rubygem-ruby-shadow && puppet agent ...` instead of the plain Puppet invocation, so that you can be sure everything is in order. You could even rebuild the Puppet package (is this SUSE?) and add a dependency on the package if that's easier for your workflow. Also, yes, `2.6.x` is quite ancient, so you're prone to get some odd results now and again.

Comment: I decided to get the rubygem-ruby-shadow installed right after the operating system installation is completed (before puppet runs). Works fine now. Thanks again!